# How to show that an induced function of a class function is still a class function?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a finite group $G$, for class functions on $H$, we define a map $\operatorname{Ind}_H^G:\mathcal{C}_H \to \mathcal{C}_G$  ($\mathcal{C}_G$ is the space of all class functions of $G$) by
$$
\operatorname{Ind}_H^G\beta(g) = \frac{1}{|H|}\sum_{x \in G }^{x^{-1}gx \in H}\beta(x^{-1}gx)
$$
for all $\beta \in \mathcal{C}_H$. then show that $\operatorname{Ind}_H^G\beta$ is still a class function.

It is clear that to show this, I have to use the fact that $\beta$ itself is a class function of $H$. But I didn't find how.  To  be precise, I want to show that for $y \in G$, when we compute $\operatorname{Ind}_H^G\beta(y^{-1}gy)$, the right hand side is nothing but of the form $\beta(h^{-1}x^{-1}gxh)$ where $h \in H$. After that we can use the fact that $\beta$ is a class function. Is my attempt wrong or I simply missed some key point? By the way I think it's pretty hard to deal with the restriction $x^{-1}gx \in H$, although it shouldn't be hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{Ind}{Ind}$The point is that this is a class function on $G$, no matter whether $\beta$ is a class function on $H$ or not - you just need $\beta$ to be a complex-valued function on $H$.

In fact, for given $g, y \in G$ you have
\begin{align}
\Ind_H^G\beta(y^{-1} g y) 
&= 
\frac{1}{|H|} \sum_{x \in G }^{x^{-1}y^{-1}g y x \in H}\beta(x^{-1}y^{-1}g y x)
\\&=
\frac{1}{|H|} \sum_{z \in G }^{z^{-1}g z \in H}\beta(z^{-1}g z)
\\&=
\Ind_H^G\beta(g),
\end{align}
where I have done the change of variable $z = y x$.